# Is there any way to increase save button size in subgrid Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is there any way to increase the size of the **save** button within Dynamics CRM editable subgrid? I was trying to do it through custom web resource script.
Script can't see the div when it is firing.

```
<button title="Save" class="cc-ds-headerbtn cc-ds-header-save-btn" style="font-size: 12px;"></button>'
```

just need to change `12px` to `20px`

Comment: any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to increase the size, anything to do with HTML DOM manipulation is unsupported in CRM and it is highly unrecommended. Because that will break silently anytime whenever future upgrade happens from CRM product if Microsoft decided to change something around that.

That being said, the size of save button being small is cruel and I agree it’s a problem for many business users. That can be solved by user training, and it’s worth to note that - the Editable subgrid has an auto-save feature, any record being edited will get their changes saved on focus out.